# How to create page with non printing annotation

Tags: pdf, pdftex

I would like to add text 'This page intentionally left blank' to blank page (with header) but I would like to this text appear in pdf but not in the printed document. Is it even possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can add the text in a Optional Contents Group (OCG) layer with print state set to off. However, I don't think there is a package that can do this yet. You might be able to modify `ocg.sty` which is distributed with `Asymptote`.

Comment: @MartinHeller There is now ocgx2 at https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2

Answer (score 9):

The `pdfcomment` package allows you to add PDF annotations to the document which are usually not printed, except if explicitly requested.
Looking at the manual I come up with this example which adds a white page behind the title page to make sure the next content is starting at an odd page.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\title{Test}\author{Tester}

% Not sure if this is right, but by default comments should not be printed anyway
%\pdfliteral{%
%    /printCommentPopups [/b false]
%}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\pdffreetextcomment[subject={overlay},height=2.2cm,width=4.8cm,voffset=-2.8cm,hoffset=1.5cm,opacity=1.0,justification=right,type=typewriter,font=Jokerman,fontsize=13pt,fontcolor=black]
    {This page was left intensionally blank.}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: One naive question - what shall be the fate of the text intermediate between \blindtext and \end{document}? Is that also not printed, or is the non-printing exclusively limited to whatever is put within the braces of the \pdffreetextcomment?

Comment: @TheDarkSide: The `\blindtext` just generates some example text and is not part of the solution but only there to have some text. In a real document there would be just your normal content. The empty page is generated by the `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` commands not by `\blindtext` and only the text in the \pdffreetextcomment` is not printed. I guess the 'blind' in `\blindtext` caused the confusion on your part, right?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is normally accomplished by adding a switch at the top of the preamble (See [How to make a switch for print vs. display versions of a document with respect to links/URLs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57181/how-to-make-a-switch-for-print-vs-display-versions-of-a-document-with-respect-t/57186#57186)).

Personally I don't like "this page intentionally left blank pages". For starters once the sentence is typeset the page is not blank anymore and it really underestimates the intelligence of readers.

So, I would rather have an epigraph or epigraphs, but modify the code to suit:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@print
\@printtrue
\def\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
    \if@print
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
       \blankpagetext@cx      
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage
    \fi
\fi\fi}
\def\blankpagetext@cx{\epigraph{We all agree that your theory is crazy. 
          But is it crazy enough?}{Niels Bohr}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The switch is a simple `\if@print`.